# Is it possible to allow a Facebook account to get a RSS feed of protected LiveJournal entries?

Tags: facebook, rss, openid, livejournal

I have a normal LiveJournal account and take full advantage of public, friends-only, and private posts.

Another person who we'll call X has a Facebook account. I know that LJ allows Facebook accountholders to log in to LJ and view friends-only entries.

I also know that LJ allows people with normal LJ accounts to view an RSS feed of protected entries using either the existing browser cookies or HTTP authentication (source: http://www.livejournal.com/support/faq/306.html).

Is it possible to allow X to get a similar RSS feed?